# How to set number format in Table with pandastable

Tags: python, dataframe, user-interface, tkinter, number-formatting

I'm writing a GUI with tkinter and it's using pandastable module to display a dataframe. I'm trying to get this number format in the pandastable's `Table`:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format
```

I looked into pandastable's documentation but couldn't find where I can set this up. There is font, alignment and color format but no number format. Thank you very many!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to edit the data going into the dataframe or edit the dataframe already in pandastable ?

What I did was just format the data going into the dataframe and then just update the table.

vals[i] = ("%.3f" % value )

df = df.append({'Time(mS)' : time_diff, 'X1' : vals[0],. . ., 'X7' : vals[7]}
,  ignore_index = True)

pt.updateModel(TableModel(df))

pt.redraw()

Comment: Hi, I wanted to have that number format shown in the Pandatable.   pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format already takes care of what shown in DataFrame